# How can I do this horizontally instead of vertically in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code in a def function so I'm only showing the code that I would like to be set horizontally instead of vertically. Does anyone know a way to get it done? I would prefer it without brackets as well.

```
values=random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
   print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are:")
   print("Die 1:", values[0]) 
   print("Die 2:", values[1]) 
   print("Die 3:", values[2]) 
   print("Die 4:", values[3]) 
   print("Die 5:", values[4])
   return values
```

output:

```
You rerolled some dice and the new values are:
Die 1: 2
Die 2: 1
Die 3: 2
Die 4: 5
Die 5: 6
```

How I want it to look

```
You rolled some dice and the new values are: 2, 1, 2, 5, 6
```

Comment: Store the values in an array, then print the array

Comment: @ibragile, like values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ?

Comment: `print(values[0]), values[1]), values[2]), values[3], values[4])` Is this not working in your case?

Comment: @Ben see my answer below.

Comment: Here is a more Pythonic way of initializing ```values```:  ```values = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(5)]```.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import random 

N = 5 # number of dice throws
values = [0] * N
for i in range(N):
    values[i] = random.randint(1,6)

# Remove brackets
str_values = [str(i) for i in values] # convert to strings
new_values = ", ".join(str_values)
print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are: {}".format(new_values))
```

**Sample Output:**

```
You rerolled some dice and the new values are: 1, 1, 6, 1, 5
```

---

If you want a function that returns the array values (all 3 types), use the following:

```
import random 

def calcVals(values, N):
    for i in range(N):
        values[i] = random.randint(1,6)

    # Remove brackets
    str_values = [str(i) for i in values] # convert to strings
    new_values = ", ".join(str_values)

    return values, str_values, new_values

N = 5 # number of dice throws
values = [0] * N

values, str_values, new_values = calcVals(values, N)
print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are: {}".format(new_values))
```

Comment: This code will pre-allocate the array of values depending on `N` (number of dice).
Then you can also keep the `values` (array of ints) or `str_value` (array of strings).
the join() function simple is there to remove the brackets of the list.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, I was trying to find a way to do this myself with the for in range but I wasn't able to figure it out. Thanks a lot dude!

Comment: Here is a more Pythonic way of initializing ```str_values```:  ```str_values = [str(random.randint(1, 6)) for _ in range(5)]```. And also you can eliminate all those lines with just: ```', '.join([str(random.randint(1, 6)) for _ in range(5)])```.

Comment: @accdias, this is a great method, but I should point out that the current way in the answer gives you the list of integers in addition to the `str_values` list. This might be useful for the OP later in their code.

Comment: @lbragile, Just return the list of integers and deal with it outside the function.  From the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Simple is better than complex." :-)

Comment: @Ibragile, hey dude, you've helped me a lot - I was wondering if you could be able to help me with something else related to this where if I get all 5 different values, I'd want it to be able to say "All different values" or if all same values, "all same values" and so on? If it's not too much hassle.

Comment: @Ben the easiest way I could think of is to cast the list of values into a set. Namely, set(values) would return the unique elements. Then you can simply count the length (using len( )) to see how many elements you have. If you have only 1 -> all are the same in the original values list. If you have 5 -> all are different (if original had 5 values). Any number between would tell you how many values differed. Let me know if this is not clear enough.

Comment: So if 3 were same values, it'd be 3 ->? I've been trying to code it, but I wasn't able to figure it out correctly

Comment: If you had values = [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]  then set(values) would give {1,2,3,4} and its length is 4. So you can see the original values list has 4 unique values. If you had values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] then set(values) would return {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. So length is 5 meaning 5 unique values in the original list.

Comment: I see, so if it was all the same values, [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] it'd only give {1} with the length only being 1? How do you set it it up in a code with the set values?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I gave you the logic and key terms to use in your code, you should attempt it and post it as a comment below where people can fix your mistakes. This seems to be a homework question (due to other SO questions being identical to it from new users) so I hesitate to give you the answer outright. Do some coding on your own so you can actually learn something new.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are: {} {} {} {} {}".format(*values))

# You rerolled some dice and the new values are: 6 6 5 5 4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are: " + ", ".join(map(str, values)))
```

Explanation for `", ".join(map(str, values))`:
What we are doing is first `mapping` the `int` in `values` to `str` and then `joining` using `,` as the separator.

Answer (score 2):

print() generates a new line by default. Also you don't need to use \n in start. To print using a single statement **placeholders** are used.

## placeholders

1. **numbers**- %d
2. **string**- %s
   At end of the string the desired values are placed.

## syntax

```py
num1=10
num2=20
print("single number: %d"%num1)
print("two numbers: %d %d"%(num1,num2)) # note the brackets after %

# Output
single number: 10
two numbers: 10 20
```

## solution to your problem

```py
print("\nYou rerolled some dice and the new values are: %d %d %d %d %d"%(values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3],values[4]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get your output in single line. You can do this like this

```
print(values[0],values[1],values[2],values[3],values[4],sep=',')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to put an alternative (and more Pythonic way of doing it), here is my take on it:

```
from random import randint


def roll_dice(n):
    return [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]


print('You re-rolled some dice and the new values are:',
    ', '.join(map(str, roll_dice(5)))
)
```

Or, if you want a better visualization of the `print()`s:

```
print('You re-rolled some dice and the new values are: ', end='')
print(*roll_dice(5), sep=', ')
```

Finally, if you don't care about the values not being comma separated, you can simply:

```
print('You re-rolled some dice and the new values are:', *roll_dice(5))
```

And here is a proof of the concept:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from random import randint
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def roll_dice(n):
...     return [randint(1, 6) for _ in range(n)]
... 
>>> 
>>> print('You re-rolled some dice and the new values are:',
...     ', '.join(map(str, roll_dice(5)))
... )
You re-rolled some dice and the new values are: 4, 3, 5, 5, 4
>>>
```